# Line numbering in Word 365 counts the line in second column but do not display them

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, numbering

I have a Word 365 document and I want to add "Line Numbering". The document has two columns. MS-Word counts the lines properly but does not show the line numbers for the second column. How can make the appear there?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as though the space between columns is too small, so that the line numbers in the right column are hidden. Select the text in both columns, and then, on the **Layout** tab, in the **Page Setup** group, click **Columns** > **More Columns**. Then increase the value of the **Spacing** field. If you don't want to have to increase the distance between columns too much, can also (or instead) adjust the distance between the line numbers and the main text. Also on the **Layout** tab, in the **Page Setup** group, click **Line Numbers** > **Line Numbering Options** (or just click the dialog box launcher in the lower-right corner of the **Page Setup** group). In the **Page Setup** dialog box, click **Line Numbers** at the bottom of the **Layout** tab, and then, in the **Line Numbers** dialog box, set the value of the **From text** field to a specific value of your choice.

Comment: Thank you very much. It indeed works now.

Comment: Solved the problem for me too 4 years later.